# git-cola installation procedure in RHEL6.7 hosts

Tags: python, git, gnu, git-cola

I need to install git-cola in RHEL6.7 hosts. Can someone help with the procedure on how to install/compile it.
Tried installing it through rpm but having many dependencies, neither we have any rpm's related for RHEl6.X version. They are available for RHEL7.x only.

Compiled through build-cola but below errors:

```
[xxx/git-cola-master/contrib]$ls
build-git-cola.sh  build-git-cola.yaml  darwin  git-cola-completion.bash  install-python2.6.sh  install-python2.6.yaml  README.md  travis-build  win32

[xxx/git-cola-master/contrib]$./build-git-cola.sh
./build-git-cola.sh: line 8: ./contrib/travis-build: No such file or directory

[xxx/git-cola-master/contrib]$
```